# need assistance with pop and push operations

Tags: stack

I'm studying for a Microsoft Exam, one of the preparation questions is as follows:

You have a stack that contains integer values. The values are pushed onto the stack in the following order: 2,4,6,8.
The following sequence of operations is executed:

Pop,
Push 3,
Pop,
Push 4,
Push 6,
Push 7,
Pop,
Pop,
Pop,

What is the value of the top element after these operations are executed?

A. 2

B. 3

C. 6

D. 7

Correct Answer: B

Why is B the correct answer?

Comment: Agree with the answer; there is *no way* 3 is still on the stack after those ops (it immediately gets popped off)

Comment: as a side comment, I used to train on sites that are basically dumps of existing exam questions. There are **often** blatant mistakes there, probably the questions were not correctly copied in the system. Don't trust the answers on these sites. Especially when there are no explanations. My personnal experience on about a thousand questions is that at least 10% of the so called solutions were wrong.

Comment: And questions from written books, more or less official, also contain mistakes !

Comment: that's kind of depressing... i've been using those preparations questions a lot

Answer (score 3):

A stack is a LIFO (Last In First Out) structure. A "Pop" deletes the last thing you put on it.

```
2 4 6 8
Pop
2 4 6
Push 3
2 4 6 3
Pop
2 4 6
Push 4
2 4 6 4
Push 6
2 4 6 4 6
Push 7
2 4 6 4 6 7
Pop
2 4 6 4 6
Pop
2 4 6 4
Pop
2 4 6
```

For me, 6 is on the *top* (meaning the next element that would be popped out) of the stack at the end, **so C would be the correct answer**

Comment: i thought the same thing...seems like this preparation question is incorrect. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the answer also... checking with code

```
namespace StackTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            Stack st = new Stack(); 
            // Starting
            st.Push(2);
            st.Push(4);
            st.Push(6);
            st.Push(8);
            // Showing state 
            ShowStack(st,"Contenido inicial");
            //Pop, Push 3, Pop, Push 4, Push 6, Push 7, Pop, Pop, Pop,
            st.Pop();
            ShowStack(st, "Quitar uno");
            st.Push(3);
            ShowStack(st, "Agregado 3");
            st.Pop();
            ShowStack(st, "Quitar uno");
            st.Push(4);
            ShowStack(st, "Agregado 4");
            st.Push(6);
            ShowStack(st, "Agregado 6");
            st.Push(7);
            ShowStack(st, "Agregado 7");
            st.Pop();
            st.Pop();
            st.Pop();
            ShowStack(st, "Quitar tres");
            ShowStack(st,"Situacion Final");   
            Console.ReadKey();
            // 2, 4 , 6 , 8
        }
        private static void ShowStack(Stack st,string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            foreach (var item in st)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
        }
    }
}
```